# Reducing DC voltage for electric drill

Tags: voltage

What is the simplest way to reduce DC voltage, but for higher current? I have an electric drill which works on 14.4v and a 20v battery. Around 20 amps, stall current is around 80.

Comment: The *simplest* way is a linear regulator, but that wastes a lot of power. The *best* way is some kind of step-down converter; a basic buck converter is pretty simple and will do the job just fine.

Comment: But i could find buck converter only up to 3A, and i need something like 90A

Comment: You'll need to make it yourself. Designing a buck converter for that high current gets difficult, but it's possible--I've done one for 100 A before.

Comment: Do you have some kind of scheme of something?

Comment: 100 A x 14.4 V = 1440 W. That seems rather high for a battery powered drill. What's the rating of the drill motor?

Comment: Not one that will be useful for you. This was designed to output 100 V at 100 A, and would need some major redesign work to work at such low voltages.

Comment: 10-20A i think but stall current is around 80A

Comment: As long as you get the frequency in the middle of a reasonable range, simple PWM is just fine for a permanent magnet motor. The inductance of the motor serves as the inductor a buck converter would use. Don't go too high in frequency though, as the motor's inductor is not designed for low losses at higher frquencies.

Comment: What if i just connect 20v battery to a 14.4v motor, ot should spin faster but will it burn or last some time and then burn?

Comment: @user You could test it. The motor might last 30 seconds before you see smoke coming out of it. You should stop at that point because the next stage is a fire.